# Ignore "Unused Entity Issue: Unused Variable" in a single file

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, warnings, llvm

I want to get rid of this compiler warning in just one file of my Xcode project. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can turn off specfic warnings in Clang using [a pragma directive and the "diagnostic" keyword](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#controlling-diagnostics-via-pragmas), like so:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-variable"

// Insert code here

#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

No unused variable warnings will be produced for the code between the push and the pop.

A second option, even more targeted, is to mark a particular variable with a [GCC-style attribute](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html), specifically, "unused". Clang honors GCC's established attributes and won't issue a warning about that one variable:

```
__attribute__((unused))
NSString * thisStringIsJustForFun = @"It's only work if somebody makes you do it.";
```

Comment: Cool! :-) Do you know how to get rid of the "dead store" one?
I tried 

#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-value" without success...

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what the flag for that one is, or if one exists. Supposedly `-fdiagnostic-show-option` will give a list of the available diagnostic switches.

Comment: This is awesome. I'm using it with `-Wunused-function`... are there any caveats etc., to using this with production code? I'm finding that Xcode doesn't accurate report unused `static void` C functions, but perhaps I'm declaring them wrong or in the wrong place... I've got them in a `.h` file before the `@interface` declaration. Thoughts? Thank you!

Comment: As far as I know, @Yar, this is exactly equivalent to passing a `-Wwhatever` flag to the compiler, just more targeted, so I don't know of any particular caveats. GCC has similar functionality; this isn't particular to Clang. Putting a `static`-ly linked function into a header doesn't really make sense to me, but I don't know how Clang handles unused warnings for such a function no matter where it's defined.

Comment: Thanks! So where would you put a `static`-ly linked function if not in a header file? It's globally shared...

Comment: I don't think it should be `static`, then, @Yar; just declare it in the header and define it in the implementation file. `static` is for functions that don't need to be visible to more than one file.

Comment: Oh... glad I asked. Thank you as always for your help, @JoshCaswell.